# PFUser Current Location sorting an array by closest ascending location

Tags: objective-c, sorting, parse-platform

Have been working on this code for the past 4 days trying to get the PFUser location to be called, which would then pull the "location". From receiving that "location" I am wanting the array of photos to be sorted in ascending order based on the user location. However, the user location is not populating properly, and it ends up as PFUser location nil.

```
(NSArray *)caches {

  PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = [PFUser currentUser][@"location"];

  PFQuery *query = [Cache query];

  [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint withinMiles:20];
  query.limit = 20;

  NSMutableArray *photoArray = [[query findObjects] mutableCopy];

  [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, 
  NSError *error){

    if (!error) {

      [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"currentLocation"];
      [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
    }
  }];

  return photoArray;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the way you're trying to do it:

1. You are using findObjects() to synchronously fetch the query results. This will block the main thread until the results are returned.  You should use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() instead.
2. Since you are using an asynchronous method to get the location and a 
   synchronous method to the query results, your query will always complete before the user's location is saved.
3. You are querying for the user's location every time you get the photos instead of using the saved value.  Ideally you'd want to save the user's location beforehand (maybe when the app launches) so that it's already set by the time you make the query.  You can even set up a timer to update the user's location every minute or a time interval of your choosing.
4. You are querying a "location" column but saving a "currentLocation".  Make sure you use the same column name to set and retrieve the location.

This is how I would recommend doing it.  Call this function upon launching the app to update the user's location in the background:

```
- (void)updateUserLocation {
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"location"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then when you need to get the photos, call this function to fetch the photos in the background:

```
- (void)getPhotosInBackground:(void (^)(NSArray *photos, NSError *error))block {
    PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = [PFUser currentUser][@"location"];

    PFQuery *query = [Cache query];
    [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint withinMiles:20];
    [query setLimit:20];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        block(objects, error);
    }];
}
```